# How to create a Post without a Form Model?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to figure out more about Post Method so my question's purpose is to understand how to Create a Post without a Form is it possible or not.

Here is what I am trying to know how to do.

I have a project where I want a user to submit a button without any forms or input from user's side only clicking on the button on the page, after pressing on the button the views are set to change a boolean field so that admin can be notified as an example.

Here is what I was thinking about in the model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the views.py:

```
class ChangeItemStatus(View):

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if form.is_valid():
            item.active  = True
            item.save()

            messages.success(self.request, 'Item Status has been Change To Active')
            return redirect("app:template_name")
```

Sorry for the noobish question aiming to have a simplified explanation with this simple example

Answer (score 0):

Just make the button a link to the url. (You would really have to get the item you want to change.)

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('bla/<int:pk>/', views.change_status, name='bla'),
```

`views.py`

```
def change_status(request, pk):
     item = Item.objects.get(id=pk)
     item.active  = True
     item.save()
     messages.success(self.request, 'Item Status has been Change To Active')
     return redirect("app:template_name")
```

`your template`

```
<a href="{% url 'bla' item.pk %}"> Click me</a>
```

I am assuming that you are passing in the item object to your template. If you are not then leave out the whole `pk` part.